# Llamar a un script por un nombre sin poner la extensión

Tags: python, python-3.7, anaconda, keyboard

quiero hacer que mi codigo:
[archivo: chat.py]

```
# modulo chat para __main__.py :)
import keyboard
import os
# end imports

string = "[Client thread/INFO] [net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiNewChat]: [CHAT] Tobi_gamer555: hola"

string2 = string[60:] # quitamos client thread info ....
string2 = string2[7:] # quitamos [CHAT]
if "si" in string2:
    string2 = string2.replace(": si", " ") # quitamos lo que dijo el chat
    nombre = string2
else:
    print(f"{string2} >>> no ha aceptado!")


print(f"{nombre} ha aceptado!")
```

pueda ser llamado en cmd (La consola de mi windows 7) poniendo "chat_bot" y no python chat_bot.py

¿como es esto posible?

Comment: un bat en un archivo que este en el path de windows? un ejecutable que este en una ruta? un bat en la carpeta donde lo ejecutas?

Comment: no, ejecutar un archivo .py sin tener que poner "python *archivo.py*"